# Dúvida impressora virtual

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde,
 Vou criar um sistema de emissão de senhas para fila de atendimento em php.
 As senhas será impressas em uma impressora não fiscal da bematech.
 A Bematech tem um uma ecf virtual fiscal,alguém conhece algum emulador não fiscal? Ou eu conseguiria fazer os testes nessa fiscal mesmo?
 E para imprimir como funcionaria ?

Comment: Só comentário que pode ajudar muita gente. As pessoas precisam parar de usar a ferramenta errada para a tarefa. PHP é uma linguagem ótima para fazer sistema web, mas não deve ser usada para resolver tudo. Por favor, parem de usar o martelo para colocar parafuso no lugar devido.

Comment: Qual ferramenta você me indicaria para o que eu preciso?

Comment: Qualquer coisa que não seja uma linguagem feita para web. C, C++, C#, Java, D, Go, Delphi, Harbour, Python, BASIC (dependendo da implementação), Embora eu não recomende, até Assembly é melhor que PHP para isto :)